How Can I Query Microsoft Graph API for Messages with Multiple Conditions?
I'm encountering difficulties while attempting to query messages from the Microsoft Graph API with multiple conditions. Specifically, I need to retrieve messages that were received within a certain time frame and were sent to a particular email address. Despite efforts, I haven't been able to formulate a query that achieves this effectively.
I attempted to construct a query using the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve messages meeting specific criteria, including a particular time frame and recipient email address. Here's an example of the queries I tried:
Original Query Attempted:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$(filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2023-06-01 and ReceivedDateTime le 2023-06-19 and ('c.smith@companyname.com' in toRecipients))

Workaround Query Used:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="to:o.smith@companyname.com AND received>=2023-06-01 AND received<=2023-06-19"

I expected both queries to filter and return the desired messages accurately. However, despite multiple attempts with variations, neither query produced the expected results. This left me unable to retrieve the targeted messages effectively.

With the Filter you can't filter on the Recipients collection so that won't work, also if you have a mailbox has multiple email addresses the To Address will always resolve to the primary address.
While nothing looks wrong with the second it best practice to bracket you KQL logic sets eg
search="(to:address@domain.com) AND (received>=2023-06-01 AND received<=2023-06-19)"
you can also use the ... between operator eg
(received:2023-06-01...received:2023-06-19)
There also the Search API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-overview which can do the same KQL type query eg


{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "message"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "(received:2023-06-01...2023-06-19) AND (to:address@domain.com)"
            }
        }
    ]
}



Also instead of the to keyword you can also use Participants which would also include the From, To, Cc fields in the search.
